# Bokeh donut chart with percentages

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I've been looking everywhere for a built-in percentage adder for the bokeh module so that I can add percentages to this plot. Does anyone know if this exists?
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery/donut_chart.html